# sitecore document manager button

Tags: button, sitecore, document-management

In Sitecore 6.4.1 is there a way to turn off permissions for the Document Manager button in the Hyperlink Manager. I have been looking through the Core database but have not found the setting to turn it off.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oXG6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 1:

The Hyperlink manager make use of the Telerik. You can check the blog post on the following link on how to modified the UI

http://www.awareweb.com/awareblog/9-21-11-hyperlinkmgr

Thanks

Comment: If the button visibility is not modified in the codebeside implementation then it would suffice to hide it in the xml. No further coding necessary

Comment: Yes it depend on the needs of the user. It can set the visibility based on user role also. But for this scenario, setting the visibility to hidden is enough

Comment: I can't seem to find an XML file that controls this. It looks like it is locked in the Telerik.Web.UI.dll. It does have an XML file but nothing I do to it seems to change anything.

Comment: Then it is not the right xml file. Sitecore make use of xml to generate the Popup. Try to inspect element, go to the network tab then click on the button that shows the document management. You will see in the network tab of the inspect element which path sitecore call the ui

Comment: Hishaam, maybe pointing Jeremy towards the correct xml would be better.. if there is any which I actually doubt.

Comment: @Gatogordo, I have not used the Sitecore 6. But from my experience, I know that Sitecore makes use of XML to generate the UI. So, if i am not mistaken, the xml file should be present in the Content Manager folder in the Website.

Comment: By making that assumption you probably have send Jeremy on a wild goose chase ;)

Comment: Yeah i know. This is why I have installed the Sitecore 6 on my machine so that i can provide more accurate info :)

Comment: I have modified the answer since the UI is based on Telerik